# What makes LastPass so secure?

Tags: firefox, security, web, lastpass

I can't simply understand how using LastPass is secure. All an attacker need to do is to compromise the single LastPass account and then he has also compromised all other websites.

What's so good about that compared to the traditional approach to have separate accounts per site?

Is it really better to have one strong master password, strong site-specific passwords that can be accessed via the master password than having weaker passwords, but different on all websites?

Comment: Exactly how are you going to remember strong passwords for several dozen sites? I'm counting 160+ credentials stored in my vault at this time. That's not even counting securely stored pin codes for cards and software license keys I'm keeping in there as well. Apart from a very few exceptions, every password in there is randomly generated, using any available character for the particular site, and of maximum length or somewhere over 20 characters. LastPass can sniff out duplicates for me and can give a report of where I'm compromising security.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Aside from allowing you to create unique, complex passwords for each site, we also offer free second factor authentication: [Grid](https://lastpass.com/help.php?topic=grid&nw=1&fromwebsite=1). So your username and password are not enough to access your data when Grid is used.

In addition, your passwords are not stored in Firefox's or IE's password managers which are generally insecure (just run our installer and watch how we can pull all of the passwords).

As for storing in the cloud, everything is encrypted locally before it is sent to the server and your key is never sent to us. You can read more about how we keep you safe on the technology page on our website.

Comment: i do appreciate the sincere integrity of your service, yet the old paranoia dies hard. and the fact that your company is based in the US of A (not too far from Washington) doesn't help much either. if agents of Homeland Security or other less-existent agencies show up, flashing credentials and reminding you of your patriotic duty i think your best intentions aren't worth much. i hope you don't mind that i prefer a local solution.

Comment: Actually, molly, it sounds like everything is encrypted and decrypted client-side - as in, they can't access anything by themselves. If that's true, I don't see why this is any less secure than having something locally.

Comment: Yes, everything is encrypted locally. We frankly don't want the liability of being able to access your sensitive data, it is an unnecessary risk that we do not want to take.

FWIW, we were ranked in pcmag's top 100 products of 2009, ranked in pcworld's best security products of 2009 and are currently being featured on google chrome's extension site as their top picks.

Comment: fair enough (although Google may not be my preference to rate privacy-related products given their track record), but the fact remains that my passwords are ultimately no longer exclusively accessible by myself when they are stored online, regardless the sophistication of protective measures.

Comment: It's nice to hear from a first-party. +1 for your "Grid" technology, that's a really smart idea. :)

Comment: @Bob Hi, I have pointed in my [blog post](http://hourlyapps.blogspot.com/2010/02/one-reason-why-we-cant-trust-online.html) one fundamental flaw of your service. How do you plan to address that flaw?

Comment: What if browser is not secure? I mean if somebody installed an extension that starts working when I get logged-in in browser. See my tweak on Android [here](http://madlabstest.com/blog/2012/08/23/tweaks-on-lastpass-and-android/)

Comment: How is it "encrypted locally" and "key is never sent to you" if I can view my passwords from multiple computers or even the website?

Comment: @Greg They store the encrypted credentials. Encryption happens client-side, using your master password and any other authentication mechanism you've activated in addition, and the encrypted data is sent to them for storage. Even if this data were compromised, decrypting it without your master password (and additional measures) is not realistically feasible. Because it's a cloud solution, you can access your data anywhere, but decryption is still only done client-side. Even when accessing your vault using the website instead of using a plugin (client scripts are used in this case).

Comment: @G_H: The "key" (i.e. master password) is never sent to you, but an locally-encrypted version of it is?  I think I was assuming that "key is never sent to you" meant somehow you didn't store any representation of the master password, which is obviously impossible.

Comment: @Greg Your master password isn't stored. Neither locally or on their servers. It is merely used to encrypt and decrypt data. Which is why you need to remember it! Suppose I've got some clever encryption scheme that requires a password for both encryption and decryption. I encrypt a file and send that to you for safekeeping. You keep it for me, but can't decrypt it. When you send it back to me, I can decrypt it with the password, that only I know. This is how it works.

Answer (score 18):

I don't consider LastPass particularly safe (like anything that is stored 'in the cloud'), I much prefer a local solution (for example, **[KeePass](http://keepass.info/)**). The convenience of having online access to login information comes at an unacceptable price (at least for paranoid old me).

Comment: KeePass has Unix (KeePassX) and Windows versions, and works from a USB drive (perfect for passwords for sites like SuperUser).

Comment: @Molly - nicely put.

Comment: @Molly It appears that the LastPass info is encrypted locally, not "in the cloud".

Comment: quite so, yet the information is no longer exclusively accessible by myself when stored on an external server. it's a trade-off, convenience for exclusiveness, a risk i'm not willing to take.

Comment: There are also android and windows mobile versions of KeePass, and probably others.

Comment: I'm using it, but the trick is to keep the key store file up to date and backed up. This is the tradeoff with the online password keepers.

Comment: I used to use KeePass. Thinking it is more secure than LastPass AND reaping the same benefits is an illusion. How are you gonna backup your KeePass database and keep all copies up-to-date? Either manually, with the risk of a carrier (like HDD, USB stick, smartphone) being stolen or breaking, or you keep it on something like Dropbox. And guess what, then you're right back to keeping stuff in the cloud. Minus the advantages of LastPass' features.

Comment: @G_H, not necessarily. What I do is use Keepass to create a database and key file + password. I setup the app so that it stores the database in a local store of an owncloud instance, and the key file in another owncloud instance (or a USB key). The password of course would be a 35+ bit secure known only to me. The owncloud files are stored encrypted on my own VPS/Dedicated server. Granted, an agency can have a warrant against the DC that provides me the server. But they will need in addition, my key file and my password. Being in the cloud does not necessarily mean it's unsafe.

Answer (score 17):

What makes it secure is simply that they cannot tell anyone what your passwords are, even with a gun to their head. Even when using the web interface, your passwords are encrypted locally before being transmitted.

Yes, it is true that it provides a "single point of failure" unless Grid is used. However, you could have a ridiculously strong master password - who cares if you have to type a 100 character password if you only do it once a day? And because it saves your "sub passwords", you can have them a lot stronger than you normally might.

Another advantage is that most people won't have different passwords for every website (or will have a pattern), and LastPass lets you ditch this. So whereas before *every single site you were on* was a potential entry point to all other sites you were on, now only your LastPass account is. Cracking any "sub password" yields no extra information to an attacker.

This is useful because you have *no idea* whether sites you are on are encrypting your password, or salting it. I could name a website with 11 million users that stores passwords unencrypted in their database.

Finally, LastPass offers features like one time passwords for accessing your passwords in untrustworthy locations, which keeps your account secure from even the most advanced keyloggers.

Comment: That's a good point.. most people reuse their password.. or have two or three that cover all bases

Answer (score 4):

Just had a quick look at their site - I think your points are correct... If someone cracks your password there, they have all your passwords - it simply bundles a few features from a few programs in to one program.

From looking there, there is nothing that makes me think it is "more secure" than having separate passwords for different sites - as you will be anyway... Last pass simply makes it easer to manage.

Comment: The Lastpass service doesn't work like that as explained in Bob's comment. What people seem to be missing nowadays is that the most insecure way to store your sensitive data and passwords is at the pc side. Many people use the insecure password features of Firefox, Chrome etc. while that is a wrong feeling of security. A good hacker, smart thief or trojan only needs a minute to get all your passwords, access your mail and other data. Lastpass doesn't have any information then encrypted rubbish on their side. How can a security agency compromise that? The key is on the pc side.

Comment: If you run the LastPass windows installer, we pull all of your passwords from IE, FF and Chrome (btw...if we can do it, any program can) and then offer you the ability to delete them. We definitely feel we are much more secure than this status quo way of remembering your passwords in the browser and we are much more convenient as well.

Answer (score 3):

It might be helpful to know Steve Gibson (of [Security Now!](http://www.grc.com/securitynow.htm) fame) referred to LastPass [in a podcast](http://www.grc.com/sn/sn-256.htm):

> ... what I have to say is, I think, the best solution possible.

In his over 600 episodes of security now, Gibson often reminds listeners the best passwords are gibberish and long. In this particular podcast he says

> ... the longer your password is, the stronger it is

Answer (score 0):

No online password storage tool can assure you security. They claim that the host proof password storage mechanism hides the passwords from the host, and only the client side knows the key and the decrypted form.

But the following blog post shows a flaw in that assertion:

[One reason why we can't trust online password storage](http://hourlyapps.blogspot.com/2010/02/one-reason-why-we-cant-trust-online.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using LastPass with the Chrome plugin I was able to pull a password by navigating to a login page, filling in the password and entering the following in the console (press <kbd>F12</kbd>).

```
document.querySelectorAll("[type=password]")[0].value
```

This is with [two-factor authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-factor_authentication) and with the "require master-password to show/copy password"-option enabled. I'm guessing it would not be hard to automate this, meaning that passwords can be pulled easily from LastPass just like other password storage, contradicting what "Bob from LastPass" seems to be claiming.

I guess LastPass is considered better than manual password management by security experts like [Steve Gibson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Gibson_(computer_programmer)) simply because the risk of compromise from a weak/reused password or by a generic keylogger is bigger than the risk from malware that's specifically attacking LastPass. Still I would only use it for sites that I can afford to lose, and never for banking/primary email/[Dropbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropbox_%28service%29), etc.

A password manager requiring two-factor authentication for every password that is downloaded from the server (LastPass only requires it on first login) would limit the damage to only the passwords that were used on the infected computer, but I have not found a password manager with that option yet.

Comment: You seem to be trying to show why LastPass is not secure by showing that Javascript code running in a web page can see passwords entered into forms on that page.  This is true, but it is still true even without LastPass running.  And it does not allow the page to get passwords out of LastPass for other sites, so you're no worse off than without it.

Comment: You are right, and I probably wasn't clear enough.

I was not trying to claim that any webpage you visit can steal your passwords with javascript. I was trying to claim that someone with access to your computer (ie. evil friend or malware on a public computer) can pull your saved passwords from LastPass, even with 2-factor and password protection on viewing passwords. 

The javascript example was just one easy way of demonstrating that.

Comment: @dschlyter I'm not sure what you're saying here.  LastPass gives you the option to either automatically fill in a password, or require you to re-authenticate yourself before filling it in.  The autofill option is always opt-in, and I never select it for sites that provide financial, email, or cloud storage services.  This means that someone who tried to use the JS trick you show would at most only get my passwords for Stack Exchange, etc.  And I'm not sure your trick is as easy to pull off as you seem to think.